# Sending a file in e-mail message body using Views Send

Tags: views, emails

I have a drupal site that holds thousands of client details. What I want to do is to create an emailer to send out campaigns to the clients.

So far I have a view set up to filter clients by company and using Views Send I can send all selected an email.

What I would like to do is to send a file in the email. Either that or be able to paste the data from the file into the email. The file is stored in my drupal site within a content type.

Does anyone know how I would be able to do this? To be able to select from a list which file to send in the e-mail message body?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the [Entity Email Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_email):

> The Entity Email module lets users create their own email templates
> which can be used to send emails. Emails sent can also be recorded in
> the DB if needed. Emails can be sent programmatically or by the mean
> of the Rules module.
>
> Main features:
>
> Built on top of the amazing entity API
>
> Allow token substitution
>
> Templates can also contain attachments (PDF, TXT...)
>
> Rules module support, so email actions can be triggered by any Rules
>
> Supports the MimeMail module for HTML emails.
>
> Build with the fields API Emails sent> can be recorded in DB

I don't know that it will integrate with Views on it's own, but you may be able to manually make it work the way you want.